# PHP, MYSQL, FOREACH check if value are all same

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

**Example:**

Mysql - table_data

```
  dataid   dataname    datastatus
    1        joel          1
    1        joelle        2
    1        joe           3
    1        joela         4
    1        joella        5
```

PHP

```
 $names = array('joel','joelle','joe','joela');
 foreach($names as $name)
 {
    $qcheck = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table_data WHERE dataname=".$name."");
     //Do checking here
 }
```

How can I know if joel, joelle,joe and joela datastatus are all same and not same?

How can I know the output of that example.. the output should be false because all of the status are not same, and In case all of the status are the same how can I know that?

Hope someone could help me thanks in advance..

Comment: I didn't get my desire answer, because my question is not accurate.. Im gonna post the real scenario..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easier way to do this would be to use `array_unique()`. If the resulting array has only one element they are all the same.

```
$sample_array = array('Joe','Joe','Joe','Joe');
if (count(array_unique($sample_array)) === 1) {
  echo 'all the same';
}
else {
  echo 'not all the same';
}
```

Output

```
all the same
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/467427)

```
$arrays = [
    ['Joe','Joe','Joe','Joe'],
    ['Joe','Joe','Joe','John']
];
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
  if (count(array_unique($array)) === 1) {
    echo 'all the same';
  }
  else {
    echo 'not all the same';
  }
  echo "\n";
}
```

Output

```
all the same
not all the same
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/467433)

Comment: Hello john, can u help me on my question?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sample_array = array('Joe','Joe','Joe','Joe');
$temp = $sample_array[0];
$same = true;

for($i = 1; $i < count($sample_array); $i++) {
    if ($sample_array[$i] != $temp) {
        $same = false;
        break;
    }
}

if ($same) {
    echo 'All same';
} else {
    echo 'Not same';
}
```

Result:

```
All same
```